# How to export lintr output to a file?

Tags: r, function, standards, lint, lintr

I am writing some scripts in R and our standard is use lintr for standardization of the code.
Please advice how can I export the output of the lint function to a txt file for example.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `capture.output()` function:

```
capture.output(lint("myscript.R"), file="lint_output.txt)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to convert the result in a dataframe and then save it in csv format.

```
result <- lintr::lint("my_script.R")
df <- as.data.frame(result)
write.csv(df, file="output_file_name.csv")
```